# How do I make a micro-controller act as a finger on a touch screen?

Tags: arduino, touchscreen, capsense

I want to make a device that I can place on a capacitive touch screen and it will start tapping the screen repeatedly. Is there any way to do this with the Arduino?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use a capacitive touch screen without a human hand](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/how-to-use-a-capacitive-touch-screen-without-a-human-hand)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done if you get an Arduino plus a servo controller that has a rig that controls a stylus. The stylus must be able to work with capacitive touch screen (not all do).

Look for Arduino Servo Controller shield

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is quite possible to do. Simply place a small piece of copper foil on the screen.  Connecting the foil to ground will simulate a finger press. You can use an N-channel FET to switch the foil between connected and not connected. The gate of the FET goes to your microcontroller.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capacitive touch screen stimulation board. Please look at this [presentation](http://www.fpl2012.org/Presentations/PHD7.pdf) and this [paper](https://www2.lirmm.fr/lirmm/interne/BIBLI/CDROM/MIC/2012/FPL_2012/Papers/PHD7.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Answers should contain at least some relevant information within them. Link only answers are not considered answers.

Answer (score 1):

Copper foil method mentioned above  the best way ...
Or you can use small  sized copper coins alternatively to the foils ...
Connect it to the grnd pin of Arduino 
And regulate the connection with an npn transistor 
Whenever you give 5v to the base of NpN the ground is established in the coin and touch is simulated