# Is it possible to drive a capacitive touch screen work as a touch simulator?

Tags: driver, capacitive, touchscreen

I want to simulate a finger touch/move/etc. on capactive touch screen. Obviously using a robot arm and stylus pen is a solution, but it was expansive and the structure was too complex. It would be elegant if we can lay something (another capactive touch screen) on the original screen and drive it to simulate a finger.

I learned that a capactive touch screen is somewhat a row/column selection capacity matrix. So is it possible to make a driver system to activite certain areas in the screen and make it recognized as a finger touch?

[The problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60070/how-do-i-make-a-micro-controller-act-as-a-finger-on-a-touch-screen) want to simulate a static touch area, but I want a CONTROLLABLE/PROGRAMMABLE
 activition of ANY area in the screen.

Comment: you could use a virtual touch screen driver .... driver reports touches from a nonexistent touch panel

Comment: A capacitive touch screen is an *input* device. You can't drive one as that would require it to be an *output* device.

Comment: One reason to simulate finger is that we don't break up a device and plug something or 'hacked' the device by software, leaving it inact.

Comment: If there is a chance you can do it, it would probably be with a projected capacitive touch screen, which has addressable wires, so perhaps you could attempt to energise an area where a wire pair crosses.  No idea whether that would work, just looked up the types of capacitive touch screens to see if one was "addressable".